# Why would my side-loaded Windows Store app go no further than the splash screen?

Tags: deployment, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, sideloading

I have a Windows Store App that, of course, runs fine on my dev machine.

After creating the package to side load for testing, I installed it on another (desktop) machine. Using the instructions for side-loading contained on pages 25 and 26 of Brundritt's free ebook "Location Intelligence for Windows Store Apps", my app seems to install just fine, except that the app is not added to the Windows 8.1 start screen at the end, as expected.

Nevertheless, I can find the app via the Search functionality - I type the name, it shows up in the "found" list (with its logo), but when I try to run it, the splash screen simply "flashes" and then the app disappears. It icon is indeed parked on the taskbar, and every time I click it, the splash screen flashes, but that's all.

This is a Windows 8.1 app that contains a Bing Map, SQLite (and sqlite-net), as well as ExifLib.

It does show up in Task Manager's "App History" tab.

How can I rectify this problem, or at least determine what the problem might be?

### UPDATE

This may (or may not be) significant: the version of the app I sideloaded was built in debug mode. Do I need to build in release mode for this to work?

Also: After building in release mode (for the first time) on the dev machine, it no longer finds the SQLite data that had formerly existed. Does changing from debug to release change the path to the database or something?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx

Comment: how would you solve finally? did it work with the Allan solution? I get an 'InvalidCastException' when call a method after instanciate

Comment: I don't recall now, but since I marked Allan's answer as correct, it must have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/28/10354327.aspx  It appears that the app needs to be built in release mode to work properly.