# Why am I unable to sideload my Windows Store App?

Tags: windows-store-apps, release, platform, configurationmanager, sideloading

I was able to at least get an earlier build of my Windows Store App, developed on my laptop, side loaded onto a desktop machine, although it [would not get further than the splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965634/why-would-my-side-loaded-windows-store-app-go-no-further-than-the-splash-screen).

With my latest build, it won't even (side) load:

[image]

Of course, it runs fine on my laptop (from VS 2013).

Something I noticed odd about the packages Visual Studio created (via right-clicking the project and selecting Store > Create App Packages, etc.) was that the Packages created indicated "Debug" builds:

[image]

I wasn't grokking why, though, because I changed the project from "Debug" to "Release" mode prior to creating the app packages (Project > Properties > Debug > Configuration == Release, Platoform == Active (x86)

But when I went back to take a screen shot of the settings, it was set to "Debug" - I don't know how/why it got back to Debug from Release. So I changed it BACK to Release, then to make sure that had "taken," I opened Build > Configuration Manager, and saw that it was set to Debug. What?!?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding just what these mean, or how they are supposed to be set, but this is what I see now:

[image]

How can I set these up so that it builds in Release mode? Is this mismatch/communication breakdown/misunderstanding the cause of the failure of the app to sideload?

**Notes:** On the Application tab of my app's properties, both "Configuration" and "Platform" are read-only and say, "N/A" - why, and is that a problem??

The Build tab, on the other hand, shows "Active (Debug)" for Configuration, and "Active (x86)" for Platform. Is this right?

If I change Configuration on the Build tab to "Release", it doesn't stick; when I close the page, it doesn't prompt to save the change, and when I open it again, it is back to "Debug"

Something which looks odd to me is the text in the "Suppress compiler warnings" text box, namely ";2008"

What does that mean?

### UPDATE

I was able to get the switch from Debug to Release to "stick" by making the change in the Configuration Manager, but if the settings available via Project > Properties are, in effect, read-only, why do they play the game of appearing as if they are editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed to install the app certificate.

Please see my answer on [sideload windows 8 apps to multiple devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524265/sideload-windows-8-apps-to-multiple-devices/31005993#31005993) for how to sideload apps